# How do I create entrypoing to go container of coredns?

Tags: docker, containers

I am pretty noob in docker containerand docker compose.

I pulled in docker compose https://github.com/codeniko/pihole-coredns-tls-docker/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

I wanted to create entry point so I can enter container.

for which I made below changes

```
 coredns_upstream:
    image: "coredns/coredns"
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    volumes:
      - "./coredns/:/etc/coredns/"
    command: -conf /etc/coredns/coreconfig-up
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: coredns_up
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    networks:
      coredns:
        ipv4_address: 172.10.10.100
```

I added these changes:

```
tty: true
stdin_open: true
```

to be able to enter,
that didnt worked so I added

```
entrypoint: /bin/bash
```

that throws error when try to run container, docker compose up

```
ERROR: for coredns_upstream  Cannot start service coredns_upstream: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/bash\": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory": unknown
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Comment: That setup will try to run a shell, as a long-running server process, instead of the actual long-running server process the container normally runs.  You can't really run an interactive shell via Compose; that's not what it's designed to do.  If this did work, what are you hoping to be able to do?

Comment: You understood it wrong . I am not trying to enter via docker compose , docker compose just runs the container. I want to be able to later enter containers

Comment: What does "enter" mean?  How do you "enter" other programs, like an nginx or Web browser running directly on your host?

Comment: What i mean is this `docker exec -ti container_name bash`

Comment: You don't need to do anything for that to work.  (`docker-compose exec ...` might be slightly easier, for being able to find the auto-generated container names.)